# Is the function $f(z)= \sqrt{xy}$ analytic??

Tags: analytic-functions

Whether the function $f(z)= \sqrt{xy}$ is analytic at the origin $(0,0)$ or not?

I want to know how to check/verify using Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Where do you think that function is defined?

Comment: @zhw.: By choosing appropriate branches, you can define it continuously in the entire complex plane.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm aware of that. But I was asking where the OP thought this function is defined.

Answer (score 1):

If it were *analytic* (rather than just differentiable) at the origin, it would be complex differentiable in an entire neighborhood of the origin. But it is not even real differentiable at $z=\varepsilon+0i$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ (consider for example $f\circ g$ with $g(t)=\varepsilon+it$).

But it can't even be *real differentible* at the origin. The partial derivatives are all $0$, but on the line $x=y$ we have $f(x+iy)=x$ -- which is *not* approximated by $0x+0y$.

Comment: @zhw, Thank you $$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
&\sqrt{xy}  \quad\text{for } (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
&0 \qquad   \;\text{ for } (x,y)=(0,0)\\
\end{cases}$$